# How to use and where to put code not part of MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote ruby code which pulls content from Google API. It works as a standalone `example.rb` file. I need to add this to my RoR app. What is the standard way to do it? How should I call this code from the controller? Should I add this code in some model file, keep the code in `/lib` folder, or put the code in `/vendor/plugins` folder?

Comment: What are you doing with the content this code is getting back from google?

Comment: This might help you out, app/services vs lib/: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159021/rails-service-objects-vs-lib-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either extract it out into a gem, or you could put it in `lib` if you wanted.

If you take the second approach, here's an example. Say you have it in a module (Google)

```
#lib/google.rb
module Google
  class Uploader
    def initialize
      ...
    end
    def foo
      ...
    end
  end
   ...
end
```

in your controller

```
require 'google'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def new
    uploader = Google::Uploader.new # do whatever here
    uploader.foo
  end
end
```

There are many ways to modify / use this module approach, the given code is only one possibility.

Comment: Alternatively, you could put the require statement in an initializer to make the library available to all controllers.